# Android show variable text from a socket connection in a EditText

Tags: java, android, sockets

This routine read the data from a socket stream (ois). The question is why it works fine showing the read data through  *System.out.println(data)* (used to debug) but it works wrong  showing "null"  in the EditText object of the android device when a data is received.

```
final EditText input_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_txt);
.....
thrd = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() { 
        while (!Thread.interrupted())
        {
            data = null;
              try {
                data = ois.readLine();
              } catch (IOException e) {     
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (data != null)
                {
                   System.out.println(data);
                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                    input_txt.setText(data+"");
                    }
                  });
                }
        }
 }
});
thrd.start();
```

-

```
-----  layout xml -------------------------------------
....
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/input_txt"
     android:layout_width="240dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="0.25"
     android:ems="10"
     android:gravity="top" >

     <requestFocus />
 </EditText>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that after you send a runnable to the UI thread your while loop resets the data value (String) back to null (See commented code).

```
//1. Reset data to null, even if 2 is not executed yet.
data = null;
    try {
    data = ois.readLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (data != null){
    Log.d("Test", data);

    //2. Start this code some where in the future...
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            input_txt.setText(data+"");
        }
    });
}
```

What you should do is create a copy of the data String so the UI thread code will have the original data value.

```
//1. Reset data to null, even if 2 is not executed yet.
data = null;
    try {
    data = ois.readLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (data != null){
    Log.d("Test", data);

    //Cache the current value
    final String dataCopy = data;
    //2. Start this code some where in the future...
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            input_txt.setText(dataCopy+"");
        }
    });
}
```